# Option tag - open page in the same tab

Tags: javascript, html

I this case how to open the page in the same tab???

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select name="menu1" id="menu1">
<option value="http://www.espn.com">ESPN</option>
<option value="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</option>
<option value="http://www.abcnews.com">ABC</option>
<option value="http://www.cbsnews.com">CBS</option>
<option value="http://www.foxnews.com">FOX</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I must to open three diferit page in the same tab I find this on the internet but I don't know how to change the code to open page the same page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate to that address in the current tab, just set the value of window.location:

```
window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, "_self" );`